# Beginner: how can I repeat this function?

Tags: r, loops, row, apply, repeat

I need R studio for analysing some data, but haven't used it for 4 years now.

Now I've got a problem and don't know how to solve it. I want to calculate the variation of some columns together in every row. With some experimentation I've found this out:

```
var(as.numeric(data[1,8:33]))
```

and I get: 1.046154

As far as I know this should be right. It should at least give me the variation for the items 8 to 33 in the column for the first person. It also works for any other row:

```
var(as.numeric(data[5,8:33]))  => 1.046154
```

Now I could of course use the same thing for every row individually, but I have 111 participants and several surveys. I tried to find a way to repeat the same command with every row but it didn't work.

How can I use the command from above and repeat it to all 111 participants?

Answer (score 0):

Without the data it is difficult to help, but I created some dummy data using rnorm. You can use apply to obtain a vector containing the variance for each row. Since it appears that your data is in character format and not numeric, I created a simple function to automatically transform it and calculate the variance.

```
set.seed(20)
data <- matrix(as.character(rnorm(3663)),
               ncol = 33,
               nrow = 111)

##basic function
obtain_variance_from_character <- function(x){
    return(var(as.numeric(x)))
}

##Calculate variances by row
variances <- apply(data_frame(data), MARGIN = 1, FUN = obtain_variance_from_character)
```